# how to display specific records for editing in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I need to display certain record (all the fields in the form populated according to that record in the form) according to textbox in form. Is there a way for me display that record without using filter or vb code? Do i need to design a query for this?

Comment: If you will accept a combo rather than a textbox, the wizard will guide you through creating a combo that selects records in your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can put an unbound textbox (or combobox) in the header of the form.  Then change the recordsource of the form to a query, just click the elipsis (...) next to the table name in the record source property and access will open the query design window for you.

You need to add all the fields to the query and in the Criteria row of the field you want to select by right click with the mouse and select "Build". You will be able to select the unbound textbox.